# Arduino Light Puzzle Help

Tags: arduino-uno

This is my first time doing this type of thing and I have no background in coding.

It will compile however the code won't upload and I've been working on this for days.

Any help you can provide would be very much appreciated.

Error messages:

```
Arduino: 1.8.8 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

Sketch uses 1898 bytes (5%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 13 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2035 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM4 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\CHRIST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_870585/sketch_apr18.ino.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.3-20171130
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM4
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9c
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9c
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9c
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9c
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9c
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9c
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9c
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9c
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9c
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9c

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Code:

```
void setup() {
//constants
// set pin numbers:
int buttonPin1 = 6; //pushbutton pins
int buttonPin2 = 7;
int buttonPin3 = 8;
int buttonPin4 = 9;
int buttonPin5 = 10;
int buttonPin6 = 11;

int const led1 = 0;      //led pins
int const led2 = 1;
int const led3 = 2;
int const led4 = 3;
int const led5 = 4;
int const led6 = 5;


  //variables

  //led pins as outputs
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led6, OUTPUT);

  //pushbuttons as inputs
  pinMode(buttonPin1, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin3, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin4, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin5, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin6, INPUT);

  //activating leds
  digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led6, LOW);

  //selecting leds to begin game

  int ran1 = random(0, 1);
  int ran2 = random(0, 1);
  int ran3 = random(0, 1);
  int ran4 = random(0, 1);
  int ran5 = random(0, 1);
  int ran6 = random(0, 1);

  //ensuring 6 led=LOW does not occur | approximatley .02 percent chance running random code twice
  if (ran1 == 0) {
    if (ran2 == 0) {
      if (ran3 == 0) {
        if (ran4 == 0) {
          if (ran5 == 0) {
            if (ran6 == 0) {
              int ran1 = random(0, 1);
              int ran2 = random(0, 1);
              int ran3 = random(0, 1);
              int ran4 = random(0, 1);
              int ran5 = random(0, 1);
              int ran6 = random(0, 1);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (ran1 == 1) {
    digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
  }
  if (ran2 == 1) {
    digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  }
  if (ran3 == 1) {
    digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
  }
  if (ran4 == 1) {
    digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
  }
  if (ran5 == 1) {
    digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(led5, LOW);
  }
  if (ran6 == 1) {
    digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(led6, LOW);
  }

  int buttonState1 = 0;
  int buttonState2 = 0;
  int buttonState3 = 0;
  int buttonState4 = 0;
  int buttonState5 = 0;
  int buttonState6 = 0;


}

void loop() {

//constants
// set pin numbers:
int buttonPin1 = 6; //pushbutton pins
int buttonPin2 = 7;
int buttonPin3 = 8;
int buttonPin4 = 9;
int buttonPin5 = 10;
int buttonPin6 = 11;

int const led1 = 0;      //led pins
int const led2 = 1;
int const led3 = 2;
int const led4 = 3;
int const led5 = 4;
int const led6 = 5;


  int buttonState1 = 0;
  int buttonState2 = 0;
  int buttonState3 = 0;
  int buttonState4 = 0;
  int buttonState5 = 0;
  int buttonState6 = 0;

  //read each pushbutton
  buttonState1 = digitalRead(buttonPin1);
  buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);
  buttonState3 = digitalRead(buttonPin3);
  buttonState4 = digitalRead(buttonPin4);
  buttonState5 = digitalRead(buttonPin5);
  buttonState6 = digitalRead(buttonPin6);

  // check if the pushbutton is pressed
  //button for leds 3 and 6
  if (buttonState1 == HIGH) {
    if (led3 == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
    }
    if (led5 == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(led6, LOW);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);

    }
  }
  //button for leds 1 and 4
  if (buttonState2 == HIGH) {
    if (led1 == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
    }
    if (led4 == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
    }
  }
  //button for leds 2 and 5
  if (buttonState3 == HIGH) {
    if (led2 == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
    }
    if (led5 == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(led5, LOW);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
    }
  }
  //button for leds 2 and 6
  if (buttonState4 == HIGH) {
    if (led2 == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
    }
    if (led6 == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(led6, LOW);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
    }
  }
  //button for leds 1 and 5
  if (buttonState5 == HIGH) {
    if (led1 == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
    }
    if (led5 == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(led5, LOW);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
    }
  }
  //button for leds 3 and 4
  if (buttonState6 == HIGH) {
    if (led3 == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
    }
    if (led4 == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
    }
  }
  //flash all lights once for winning
  if (led1 == LOW) {
    if (led2 == LOW) {
      if (led3 == LOW) {
        if (led4 == LOW) {
          if (led5 == LOW) {
            if (led6 == LOW) {
              digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
              delay(1500);
              digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
              digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
              delay(1500);
              digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
              digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
              delay(1500);
              digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
              digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
              delay(1500);
              digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
              digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
              delay(1500);
              digitalWrite(led5, LOW);
              digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
              delay(1500);
              digitalWrite(led6, LOW);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I could compile your code just fine. No compiler errors. Though it's not that useful to define the pins as constants inside setup and loop. Just use global variables.

Comment: So the problem is not compilation but uploading. Have you chosen the correct COM port?

Comment: I believe so. It only lists one port "COM4(Arduino/Genuino Uno".

Comment: You also have logic errors in your code. You have `if (led5 == HIGH)`, which will NOT check the state of the LEDs pin, but will compare the LEDs pin number, which is constant 4 here, to HIGH, which is defined as 1. This is always false. You have to do a `digitalRead(led5)`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I went through and changed all the logical errors. 
 l5=digitalRead(led5);
    if (l1 == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(led1, LOW);           It doesn't have any issues from what I can tell other than it not uploading so I believe it is an issue with my computer now. Again thank you so much.